# Mayavi combining two implicit 3d surfaces

Tags: python, plot, 3d, mayavi

I use Mayavi to plot implicit 3d surfaces and I would like to combine those surfaces into one plot. However, when I do this I get something similar like this:

[image]

The code I am using:

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

A=0.24639243776
B=5.39100472027e-17
C=1.71555149594
D=1.72967325617
E=7.50535440036
F=-1.17072847143
G=1.0

x, y, z = np.ogrid[-3:1:100j, -10:1:100j, 0:3:100j]

def Fun (x,y,z, A,B,C,D,E,F,G):
    F1 = (x - A + y - B) / 2 + np.sqrt(((x - A - y + B) / 2) ** 2 + C * z ** 2)
    F2 = np.sqrt(x*((F*y)/2 + (E*x)/D) + y*((F*x)/2 + (D*y)/E) + G*z**2) - np.sqrt(D*E)
    F1 [F1 < 0] = F2 [F1 < 0]
    return F1

Fu = Fun (x,y,z,A,B,C,D,E,F,G)

mlab.contour3d(Fu, contours = [0])
mlab.show()
```

The problem is that no matter how I do it one of the surfaces is very low poly! I had plotted the same in Mathematica and it produces a perfect plot:

[image]

I do not expect to get the same quality plot as Mathematica is a commercial product. But at least I would like for both surfaces to be smooth.

If Mayavi is not the right tool for the task, maybe you could recommend something different with which I could achieve the desired result.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The key is to set the surface to None for it to be trimmed. Then the other surface can be drawn in the same fashion. Furthermore for the surface to be plotted according to scale, x,y,z has to be also passed into the contour3d

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

A=0.24639243776
B=5.39100472027e-17
C=1.71555149594
D=1.72967325617
E=7.50535440036
F=-1.17072847143
G=1.0

x, y, z = np.mgrid[-3:1:300j, -10:1:300j, 0:3:300j]

def Fun1 (x,y,z, A,B,C,D,E,F,G):
    F1 = (x - A + y - B) / 2 + np.sqrt(((x - A - y + B) / 2) ** 2 + C * z ** 2)
    F2 = np.sqrt(x*((F*y)/2 + (E*x)/D) + y*((F*x)/2 + (D*y)/E) + G*z**2) - np.sqrt(D*E)
    F1 [F2 > 0.0] = None
    return F1


def Fun2 (x,y,z, A,B,C,D,E,F,G):
    F1 = (x - A + y - B) / 2 + np.sqrt(((x - A - y + B) / 2) ** 2 + C * z ** 2)
    F2 = np.sqrt(x*((F*y)/2 + (E*x)/D) + y*((F*x)/2 + (D*y)/E) + G*z**2) - np.sqrt(D*E)
    F2 [F1 > 0.0] = None
    return F2

Fu1 = Fun1 (x,y,z,A,B,C,D,E,F,G)
Fu2 = Fun2 (x,y,z,A,B,C,D,E,F,G)

mlab.contour3d(x,y,z,Fu1, contours = [0])
mlab.contour3d(x,y,z,Fu2, contours = [0])
mlab.show()
```

And here is the result:

[image]